# Testing out OpenAM functionality

Tags: web-services, single-sign-on, openam

I have an openam implementation setup on openam.mywebsite.com, how does one go about testing this locally on my development environment? (localhost)
When I access openam.mywebsite.net:8080/openam/XUI/#login, and log in. It does indeed create a cookie with the name "iPlanetDirectoryPro" for the domain "mywebsite.net".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting a domain cookie, by default , the 'enduser dashboard' shows up as well, when authentication was successful.

You can also check OpenAM log 'amAuthentication.access' for successful authentications. By default it's located in the the 'openam/log' sub-directory within OpenAM configuration directory.